# Can't print to HP Officejet 5740 using elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya, printer

I installed hplip, and then attempted to set up my printer using a variety of methods including the built-in printer app, the HP device manager, the system-config-printer command, and the CUPS web interface.  None of these have been successful, as, without fail, the computer will send a page to be printed, the printer will say it is printing, and then it does not print anything.  The printer will say the job is completed, the computer says the same, and yet there will be no noise coming from the printer, and no page will come out.

Comment: Please try to set up your printer with `hp-setup`... EDIT: doh! you already tried :/

Comment: Remove the printer from system preferences
Try > hp-setup -u

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official HPLIP-Database](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_5740_series.html) your printer needs HPLIP version 3.14.10 or newer.
Unfortunately elementary OS supplies HPLIP 3.14.3 by default, which does not support your printer.

You will need to install [a newer version of HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html) (choose Ubuntu 14.04 as distribution).

**Please create a backup of your system before installing a third-party Application, just in case something goes wrong.**

Comment: Also, one thing worth pointing out: while installing the newer driver, the installation will not recognize that elementary OS is actually built on top of Ubuntu 14.04. The installation will test whether or not you're running Ubuntu 14.04, and once it figures out you're not, you'll have to install every dependency manually (which requires a bit of patience and Googleing).